# my responsive menu doesn't work in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

i made a responsive **menu-bar** that collapsed in screen **max-width=850 pixel**. it is working correctly in  *desktop different sizes*. but doesn't work in **mobile devices**. 
[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[responsive](/questions/tagged/responsive)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[menu-bar](/questions/tagged/menu-bar)[media-query](/questions/tagged/media-query)[css](/questions/tagged/css)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

```js
  

  $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".showMenu").click(function(){
        $(".objs").slideToggle("slow");
       });
      });
```

```css
   

 #menu{
     background-color: gray;
     height: 50px;
    }

    .obj{
     display: inline-block;
        background-color: wheat;
        margin: 2px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 26px;
        border:0;
    }

    .showMenu {
     display: none;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: inherit;
        border: 0;
        color: black;
        outline: 0;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 850px){
     .objs{
      display: block !important;
     }
     .obj{
      display: inline-block !important;
     }
     .showMenu{
      display: none;
     }

    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 850px){
     .objs{
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: wheat;
     }
     .obj{
      width: 90%;
     }
     .showMenu{
      display: block;
     }

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Responsive Menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="menu">
  <button class="showMenu">MENU</button>
  <div class="objs">
   <button class="obj">1</button>
   <button class="obj">2</button>
   <button class="obj">3</button>
   <button class="obj">4</button>
   <button class="obj">5</button>
   <button class="obj">6</button> 
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your HTML head

Comment: it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  below coded the header tag of your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```